# Finding out Arduino's port name on Android

Tags: android-device-manager, android-mini-pc

Since I found this app named QPython for Android, just wondering if it possible to read serial data of Arduino on Android using Python (QPython).
It would have probably been easier if I had a rooted device, so that I could just use the Termux app and `cd /dev` to find out the connected devices and their ports. but, question being, is it possible to find the port for the Arduino connected to my Android via OTG? and yes, my phone supports connection over the OTG since ArduinoDroid works very well.

Comment: you can use sl4a, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801241/interfacing-android-usb-port-with-sl4a-python/44817870#44817870)